Can somebody help me with downloading the bcp package as it is not woking in my R
I want to download the 'bcp' package in R. However this is not working and I get the following warning: Warning in install.packages :
package ‘bcp’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html
I changed my  R version to 4.0.3 to see if this worked but it didn't. I looked it up on the R website and they say the the 'bcp' package has been removed from their repository.
Does anybody know how I can get the bcp package installed in R
Kind regards, Sophie

apparently, bcp is no longer on CRAN repository. You can try to install it offline, using the tar files here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bcp/

However, what's the point to using an ancient package that is apparently no longer maintained?
